# clang ignoring CXXFLAGS?

Tags: c++, macos, clang, llvm

I'm trying to use the llvm library for making my own language on mac and have experienced nothing but pure developer pain for the last 72 hours. I got sick of the ____ at one point and in a fit of rage, brew installed llvm and symlinked all the bin stuff into /usr/local/bin, the includes into /usr/local/include, and the lib files and dirs into /usr/local/lib. Don't know if this has totally screwed me but it works great in terms of getting all the llvm binaries like llvm-config to work. But I didn't realize that clang doesn't actually by default include /usr/local/include and /usr/local/lib on mac and now I have the following problems:

1. When I use the VS Code terminal, it seems to have already defined CXXFLAGS to what I set it to (-I/usr/local/include) so my `export CXXFLAGS="-I/usr/local/include $CXXFLAGS"` leads to `-I/usr/local/include -I/usr/local/include` in my VSCode terminal instead of `-I/usr/local/include` like everywhere else. Removing that line from .zshenv makes there only be one instance of `-I/usr/local/include` but only in VSCode and everywhere else, CXXFLAGS is empty.
2. When I run clang++, it seems to simply ignore CXXFLAGS as 1. that `-I/usr/local/include` simply does not appear in the -v output and 2. I get header files not found. clang -v <a file which links a header which links llvm/ADT/StringRef.h> gets me

```
Homebrew clang version 16.0.6
Target: x86_64-apple-darwin22.5.0
Thread model: posix
InstalledDir: /usr/local/bin
ignoring nonexistent directory "/usr/local/bin/../include/c++/v1"
 "/usr/local/Cellar/llvm/16.0.6/bin/clang-16" -cc1 -triple x86_64-apple-macosx13.0.0 -Wundef-prefix=TARGET_OS_ -Werror=undef-prefix -Wdeprecated-objc-isa-usage -Werror=deprecated-objc-isa-usage -emit-obj -mrelax-all -disable-free -clear-ast-before-backend -disable-llvm-verifier -discard-value-names -main-file-name interface.cpp -mrelocation-model pic -pic-level 2 -mframe-pointer=all -ffp-contract=on -fno-rounding-math -funwind-tables=2 -fcompatibility-qualified-id-block-type-checking -fvisibility-inlines-hidden-static-local-var -target-cpu penryn -tune-cpu generic -mllvm -treat-scalable-fixed-error-as-warning -debugger-tuning=lldb -target-linker-version 857.1 -v -fcoverage-compilation-dir=/Users/me/Desktop/cpp/my-jit -resource-dir /usr/local/Cellar/llvm/16.0.6/lib/clang/16 -isysroot /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX13.sdk -internal-isystem /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX13.sdk/usr/include/c++/v1 -internal-isystem /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX13.sdk/usr/local/include -internal-isystem /usr/local/Cellar/llvm/16.0.6/lib/clang/16/include -internal-externc-isystem /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX13.sdk/usr/include -fdeprecated-macro -fdebug-compilation-dir=/Users/me/Desktop/cpp/my-jit -ferror-limit 19 -stack-protector 1 -fblocks -fencode-extended-block-signature -fregister-global-dtors-with-atexit -fgnuc-version=4.2.1 -fcxx-exceptions -fexceptions -fmax-type-align=16 -fcolor-diagnostics -D__GCC_HAVE_DWARF2_CFI_ASM=1 -o /var/folders/3c/19fgfp_j1x9g2jc2vq1990y80000gn/T/interface-f52ffb.o -x c++ src/compiler/interface.cpp
clang -cc1 version 16.0.6 based upon LLVM 16.0.6 default target x86_64-apple-darwin22.5.0
ignoring nonexistent directory "/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX13.sdk/usr/local/include"
ignoring nonexistent directory "/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX13.sdk/Library/Frameworks"
#include "..." search starts here:
#include <...> search starts here:
 /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX13.sdk/usr/include/c++/v1
 /usr/local/Cellar/llvm/16.0.6/lib/clang/16/include
 /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX13.sdk/usr/include
 /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX13.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks (framework directory)
End of search list.
In file included from src/compiler/interface.cpp:2:
src/compiler/lib.hpp:4:10: fatal error: 'llvm/ADT/StringRef.h' file not found
#include "llvm/ADT/StringRef.h"
         ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
1 error generated.
```

I really just want to just #include the files I want that are installed where they should be and have it work like everybody else.

Comment: `CXXFLAGS` is not used by clang, it's used by build generators and make programs. Set `-I` to clang directly.

Comment: @273K Huh. Could have sworn the documentation talked about CXXFLAGS being used by clang. Thank you! That does solve half the equation (the main one).